# Progress bar in real Report pull program is taking time python

Tags: python

Trying to implement progress bar in python for a report pull program.
due to multiple for loop by progress bar its taking long time to pull report. excluding the progress bar is report pull is very less time.

```
from tqdm import tqdm 


def loading(count):  
    for i in tqdm (range (count), desc="Loading..."): 
        mw_get(data) 

          # for loop inside a for lopp is taking time . any idea to mitigate
def mw_get(data):

 # data comes from another function , with 5000 entries. 
    for i in data:
        
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # sample data

    data = []
    data_len = 5000

    for i in range(data_len):
        data.append(i)

    loading(data_len)
```

Comment: Use 2 threads: one for the display/print/gui thing ... and one another for the computing/calculations. So the loading part is not slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a problem with the library itself that is causing it to slow down.

Why not try 'progress' instead?
This one looks well documented: https://pypi.org/project/progress/

Or, try going into the code of tqdm and remove the unnecessary code, and modify it to make it faster?
It would be great if you could publish that on PyPI too!